# why is falcon 25% slower on cpython 3.5 than on cpython 2.7

Tags: python, falconframework

I took the following picture from the falcon homepage:
https://falconframework.org/

[image: falcon performance]

As we can see that falcon on python 2.7 runs 24k requests/sec and on python 3.5 it runs 18k requests/sec. What could be the reason? Is this a problem with python 3.5 itself?

Comment: It'll be the difference between handling text (Unicode) everywhere, vs. bytestrings. From the benchmark description: *and finally returns a 10 KiB plain-text body, randomly generated.* In Python 3 that'll be all Unicode text, and it may be inefficient in how it handles encoding / decoding . You'd have to tease apart the benchmark into components that you can individually test to be certain however.